# Do modules have to be defined over rings with unity?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

This is definition for left module over a ring $R$  given in Wikipedia:

> Suppose that $R$ is a ring and $1_R$ is its multiplicative identity. A left $R$-module $M$ consists of an abelian group $(M, +)$ and an operation $\cdot\;: R \times M \to M$ such that for all $r, s \in R$ and $x, y \in M$, we have:
>
> 1. $r \cdot ( x + y ) = r \cdot x + r \cdot y$
> 2. $( r + s ) \cdot x = r \cdot x + s \cdot x $
> 3. $  ( r s ) \cdot x = r \cdot ( s \cdot x )$
> 4. $1_R \cdot x = x $

But then it necessary that the ring $R$ should be a ring with unity. Then why it is not mentioned in definition  ?

Comment: Module theory is a mess when the ring is non unital.

Comment: Note part 4. It makes no sense without unity, but without it, you will get a lot of pathological examples.

Answer (score 1):

Some authors use the term "ring" to mean "ring with identity." This is neither standard nor nonstandard; there is just no consensus. Authors using this definition would use the term "rng" to denote a ring that possibly does not have an identity.

Comment: @CameronWilliams technically the question is "why is it not mentioned in the definition?"

Comment: What happens if we replace the condition that $1_{R}$ is multiplicative identity of $R$,  but continue the other part.  That means $1_{R}.x=x$ for all $x \in M$ ?

Comment: @Madhu $\mathbb Z_2$ acts on $\mathbb Z_6$ via multiplication by 3 and this does not satisfy that axiom but otherwise is consistent with the devotion.

Answer (score 1):

When that definition says

> Let $R$ be a ring and $1_R$ its multiplicative identity...

they **are** mentioning (implicitly) that they are requiring $R$ to be unital.

**However**, it is certainly possible to define modules over a non-unital ring; just throw out statement 4 from that definition.